# Process CSV file containing URLs to replace possibly wrong "default" ports with explicitly stated ones

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed

I have URL/port statements in a CSV file where some port statements are wrong "default" values.

Sample input data

```
http://example.com, 80
https://lookup/bin/search, 443
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org:8115,80
century.testing.external-abc03:6112,80
century.testing.external-abc03:6112,80
https://century.testing.internal-abc03:6112,443
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org:8115,80
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org:8117,80
```

- If a port number is explicitly stated in the URL, I want to overwrite the "default port" of 80 in column 2 by the actual port as stated behind the `:`.
- If the line starts with `http://`, the port should be 80, and in case of `https://` it should be 443. However, if a port is explicitly stated, I want that port to be printed in column 2.
- I also want to remove duplicate lines.

Desired output

```
http://example.com, 80
https://lookup/bin/search, 443
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org,8115
century.testing.external-abc03,6112
https://century.testing.internal-abc03,6112
testecho345.unix.abc1200.org,8117
```

I tried with the below script but not getting expected output.

```
    grep -P  '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|\.uri|\.endpoint)' 4file|sed 's/com.*/com/'|sed 's/org.*/org/'|grep '^[^#]'|sed '/.com\|.org\|10.\|17./!d'|awk '{split($0,a,"#"); print a[1]}'|awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[1],a[2]}'|awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[1],a[2]}'|sed -E 's/^([^:]*):([^,]*),.*$/\1,\2/'|sed 's/^\|#/,/g'|awk '/http:\/\//  {print $2,80}
       /https:\/\// {print $2,443}
       /Points/     {print $2,"9042"}
       /host/       {h=$2}
       /port/       {print h,$2; h=""}'|awk -F'[, ]' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){print $i,$NF}}'|awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$1=$1} 1'|sed '/^[0-9]*$/d'|awk -F, '$1 != $2'|sed -E 's_^https?://__'
done |awk '!a[$0]++
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that you basically want to replace the `:` by a `,`, and omit any _additional_ comma-separated field from the line? Also, I am not sure if I understand your comment "If http then print 80 and https then print 443", since your sample data doesn't contain "https" and the two lines starting "http" and "htttp" (??) are unchanged in your output. If possible, please provide more examples.

Comment: @AdminBee Not replacement of (:) and (,) .. after semicolon there is number that number need to be printed in the next column regarding the http i have kept overall idea

Comment: I understand that you don't want to replace the `:` after `http:`. What I don't understand is that you say "if http then print 80". Does that mean that there can be lines in your _input file_ starting with `http:` that don't have the port number at the end, and where you want the port to be appended in the output file?

Comment: Yeah correct, some entries have the port in the URL and some entries don't have the port entries. That's the reason by default considering http/https port numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work with `awk`:

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '/^http:/ {$2=80} /^https:/ {$2=443} \
$1~/:[0-9]+$/ {n=split($1,f,":"); $2=f[n]; sub(/:[0-9]+$/,"",$1);} !already[$0]++' input.txt
```

This will interpret the file as comma-separated for input (`-F','`) and output (`-v OFS=','`).

- If a line starts with `http:`, the second column will be set to 80
- If a line starts with `https:`, the second column will be set to 443
- In all lines (including those already processed by the previous rules), if the first field ends with `:` and then more than one digit, extract that last part and set this as the content of the second column while removing it from the first column.
- The occurence count of every line will be recorded in the array `already`. Only if that is 0 for the current line, the content of the line will be printed. This makes use of the `awk` shorthand notation that a `1` (or actually a number > 0) appearing outside of the rules means "print the line including all transformations made so far", whereas a `0` means "don't print the line", and that the postfix `++` operator increases the occurence count *after* it was evaluated for the logical "NOT".

It should work with GNU `awk`, `mawk` and `nawk`.

Note that it is rarely necessary to combine `awk`, `sed` and `grep` in pipeline constructs; usually one of the three will be able to perform the entire task alone.

Comment: Than you for your answer, as a side note i have one more question if the line starts with the http or https and if there a number in that URL, how will it works?

Comment: Updated the answer with a solution that will also work when the URL has both protocol specifier and port number.

Comment: Thank you @Adminbee

Comment: Once again, whoever downvoted is welcome to provide _constructive_ criticism.

Comment: Yes, i agree with @adminbee